# QlikView not able to retain session in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, qlikview, http-status-code-500

We are loading documents from QlikView in our application. There is a weird thing happening, when I am loading the screen through Chrome or IE Edge browser everything is working fine, but when I am opening the same page through IE 11, it is landing to QlikView login screen, I feel it is not able to retain the session. But the question is why only in IE 11 that too it is differing between IE 11 versions. For few versions it is working but in few it's not.

I saw the network tab in IE and found that Qlikview makes an additional GET request to

> Authenticate.aspx?keep=

and one of the request header is: `Connection: Keep-Alive` which is returning **500 - internal server error.**

Has anyone faced this issue? TIA